How does a society domesticate the spectacled bear?
Spectacled bears are native to Andean South America. Despite being the giant short-faced bear's nephew (also know as one of the largest land mammalian carnivores ever), they are arguably the world's second most herbivorous ursid species (the number 1 is naturally the giant panda). They are also the hippies of the bear world, in the sense that almost no humans ever died from a spectacled bear attack, and every time that had happened, the human was always to blame (contrary to polar bears which do see humans as food).
So, I imagine an alternate universe where the first South American humans domesticated spectacled bears at the same time period they domesticated caviids (capybaras and Guinea pigs). They wanted to domesticate spectacled bears for at least four purposes: food, guarding, working, and as pets.

??? There is only one way to domesticate animals intentionally: take (very) youg animals, rear them in a human environment, cull those who don't fit in, breed those who fit it. Repeat for a number of generations; the famous experiment of Dmitry Belyayev and Lyudmila Trut with foxes has shown that even as few as six to ten generations might be enough to get to a fairly well domesticated race. Of course, intentional domestication is not the only form of domestication; for example, cats sort-of self-half-domesticated themselves, and most of them never ever got to full domestic status.

-1 for lack of research. Not only have we answered "how does one domesticate X?" on this site many times, the Internet is replete with information about how to domesticate animals and whether or not an animal can be domesticated. Per [ask] you're required to do your due diligence before asking here as SE is not intended to be a free research service.

@AlexP the russian fox experiment showed no such thing, they started with foxes from fur farms that had been bred in captivity for many generations. It was NOT a good measure of how long domestication takes from wild stock.

@John: At worst, that would only push the beginning of the process of domestication to the 1880s instead of the 1960s. I don't think that this makes a material difference.

@AlexP its a big diffrence for a time estimation, it means even under the best estimate the experiment only covers one third of the time involved. 30-50 generations in total.

The Russian fox experiment only shows just how much variability there is within the canid genome, not whether any of the Ursidae species can be domesticated.  Some bear species have a period while young where they can be trained as that is the time when they follow their mother around to learn bear life. But after about two years, they break away and go solitary. That solitary nature makes domestication extremely difficult.

@DavidR Cats are also very solitary in nature, and they (self) domesticated nevertheless.

@Trish Cats do have a social structure, just a more diffuse one. More importantly, we can survive a dispute with a house cat but rarely with a bear.
